# Column 'date_start' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1052

I wanna SELECT some date, but i have problem with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT `clients_agreements`.`date_start` , `buildings`.`id` ,
    `buildings`.`street` , `buildings`.`street_nr` ,
    `clients`.`building_id` , `clients_agreements`.`user_id`, `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id`, `clients_agrees_perss`.`client_agreement_id`
FROM `clients_agreements`
LEFT JOIN `buildings`
    On `clients_agreements`.`user_id` = `buildings`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `clients`
    ON `clients`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `clients_agrees_conds`
    ON `clients_agreements`.`user_id` = `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `clients_agrees_perss`
   ON `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id` = `clients_agrees_perss`.`user_id`
WHERE `date_start` = (CURRENT_DATE)
```

I get this:

> error #1052 - Column 'date_start' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: `date_start` is present in multiple table, you need to add the table name for the one you want to use, just like the other fields in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where clause should contain alias for `date_start` to point to particular table:

```
        SELECT DISTINCT `clients_agreements`.`date_start` , `buildings`.`id` , `buildings`.`street` , `buildings`.`street_nr` , `clients`.`building_id` , `clients_agreements`.`user_id`, `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id`, `clients_agrees_perss`.`client_agreement_id` 
        FROM `clients_agreements` 
        LEFT JOIN `buildings` On `clients_agreements`.`user_id` = `buildings`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `clients_agrees_conds` ON `clients_agreements`.`user_id` = `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `clients_agrees_perss` ON `clients_agrees_conds`.`user_id` = `clients_agrees_perss`.`user_id` 
        WHERE `clients_agreements`.`date_start` = (CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: How do you know this is the right alias/table though?

Comment: He has used same column as @JustNone used in his question's select statement

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause add the table name next to it like

`clients_agreements`.`date_start` = CURRENT_DATE